# Wordpress: mark navigation with "new" posts

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a way to put a "new" label in my navigation when there is a new post in that section. I have 3 main sections (1 standard posts and 2 custom post types), so if one of those sections have a new post, the navigation for that section will feature a "new" label for a limited time.

In a very basic sense, I'm looking to do: 
**If post type X has a new post within the past 7 days, add class "new"**

I have found a way to highlight a new post within a single post, but I want it to be featured on the global navigation across the site (shown here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-statusflagribbon-for-posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a bit of php you will find it easy by using the `wp_get_recent_posts` function :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Something like :

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

if (strtotime($recent_post[0]['post_date']) > strtotime('-7 days'))
    $class = "new!";
?>
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works perfectly. In my mind I had a really complex thing going, but wp_get_recent_posts does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We've made plugin for that called ["Mark New Posts"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mark-new-posts/), it is available on wordpress.org site and via plugin search in your administration console.